# Hibernate - 2 open windows record overwrites other

Tags: hibernate

I have some sort of Hibernate bug that is probably very simple to solve yet I cannot figure it out.  I am using Spring & Hibernate & MS SQL.
I have a Employee object A that I select to edit from a list. If I open that Employee A in one tab then if I open Employee B in another tab.  If I then submit Employee A while B is still open it saves the data from A into B - overwriting B.
I've looked at my Equals & Hashcode and I have a Version column and even tried messing with the isolation level of SQL. I still haven't figured it out.  This is becoming a major problem as often a user will open two Employees at the same time in order to copy from one to the other. I don't use annotations and use java + hbm files for my mappings.
Here's my equals & hashcode

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if ((this == other)) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(other instanceof Employee)) {
        return false;
    }
    Employee castOther = (Employee) other;
    return this.userLogin.equals(castOther.getUserLogin());
}

public int hashCode() {
    return new HashCodeBuilder().append(this.getUserLogin()).toHashCode();
}
```

Here's my Version declaration in my hbm

```
<version name="version" column="VERSION" unsaved-value="negative" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Though your question is more than a bit vague, a guess would be that your webapp is using a cookie to store the identifier and submitting the updates to fields according to the value in that cookie.  That is, open A (cookie set to A.Id), edit A, open B in new tab (cookie to B.Id), edit B, save A (wrong cookie ID!) and then A.values -> B.values.
Just an uninformed guess, though.